# Unable to access WiFi repeater configuration

Tags: wifi-configuration, repeater, wireless-extender

Thanks to a Virgin Superhub I now have to reconfigure my WiFi repeater, I have it connected to the computer with a cable but when I attempt the access the configuration I am told that the page is timing out.

I have tried to access in Chrome, IE and Firefox.

Comment: If the original IP address of the repeater has been changed, do a factory reset (usually holding a reset button while powering on) to put it back to what you expect it to be... or make sure your computer has an IP address assigned that is in the same subnet as the repeater (usually requires manually assigning a static IP).

Comment: Connect to the (correct) local ip address assigned to the repeater, unless you disable the web administrator, it should ask you to log into it.